# Prove that a conditional probability is a valid probability space

Tags: probability, solution-verification, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

Let $(Ω, P(·))$ denote a probability space and suppose that B is an event in this space where $P(B) > 0$.

Prove that $(Ω, P(·|B))$ is a valid probability space by showing that it satisfies the three axioms:

1. $P(A|B) ≥ 0$ for all events $A ⊆ Ω$.
2. $P(Ω|B) = 1$.
3. For any two mutually exclusive events C and D in $Ω, P(C \cup D|B) = P(C|B) + P(D|B)$.

So far I have:

1. $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$, since $P(B) > 0$ and $A ⊆ Ω$ (we know that A is non-negative), then $P(A \cap B) ≥ 0.$ Therefore, the numerator $≥ 0$ and denominator $> 0$, so $P(A|B) ≥ 0$
2. $P(Ω|B) = \frac{P(Ω \cap B)}{P(B)}$. I think we can observe that $P(Ω \cap B) = P(B)$ because $B$ is in the space of $Ω$, so $P(Ω|B) = \frac{P(B)}{P(B)} = 1$, but I'm not sure how to show it
3. We know that if two events are mutually exclusive, then $P(C \cup D) = P(C) + P(D)$.  From there I'm not sure if we can jump to the fact that $P(C \cup D|B) = P(C|B) + P(D|B)$

I'm not sure if my logic is correct and would greatly appreciate feedback/improvements.

Comment: Can you apply the rule for conditional probabiliy as you did in step 1 and 2?

Comment: For 2, you have successfully shown it. What you wrote is correct. $$B\subseteq \Omega \Longrightarrow \Omega\cap B = B$$

Comment: @Fakemistake I did apply it, but I wasn't sure how to get from $\frac{P(C \cup D \cap B)}{P(B)}$ to $\frac{P(C \cap B) + P(D \cap B)}{P(B)}$ so I abandoned that approach. Is there some property or rule that I can use?

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Thanks!

Comment: By set theory, $(C\cup D)\cap B = (C\cap B)\cup (D\cap B)$. This is known as "Intersection distributes over union". Then because $C\cap D = \emptyset$, you also have $(C\cap B) \cap (D\cap B) = \emptyset$, implying you still have a disjoint union. Now, apply the probability of a disjoint union is equal to the sum of the probabilities from the original probability space: $$P((C\cap B)\cup (D\cap B)) = P(C\cap B) + P(D\cap B)$$

Comment: I see. So you calculated that we had a disjoint union because $P((C∩B)∪(D∩B)) = P(C∩B)+P(D∩B)-P((C∩B)∩(D∩B))$, but since $P((C∩B)∩(D∩B)) = 0$, then $P((C∩B)∪(D∩B))=P(C∩B)+P(D∩B)$

Comment: You don't have to mention the rule $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$, which is indeed right, but not necessary: I think it'S better to refer the definition of $P$. You know that $P$ is a probability measure, which satisfies the countable additivity, and that $C\cap B$ and $D\cap B$ are disjoint sets. Then by definition of $P$ you automatically have $P((C\cap B)\cup (C\cap D))=P(C\cap B)+P(C\cap D)$.